# 11 birds in 3 same cages

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, contest-math, combinations

> How many ways can we put 11 birds in 3 identical cages if we put at least 3 birds in every cage?

**Is this correct:** We can arrange birds so that we have 3,3,5 or 3,4,4 birds in cages.

- first case: We select 5 birds for first cage and then 3 for second and we put last 3 in last cage. Clearly we must divide thi by 2 since if we put say birds $1,2,3$ and $4,5,6$ in third it is the same if we put $4,5,6$ second and $1,2,3$ in third cage. So we have $${1\over 2}{11\choose 5}{6\choose 3}$$ ways to do this.
- second case: We get
  $${1\over 2}{11\choose 3}{8\choose 4}$$
  Now we add this and we are done?

Comment: Can we not have cages contain $0$, $0$, and $11$ birds?

Comment: @AndrewChin Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Are birds identical or distinguishable?

Comment: How can two birds be the same?  @MathLover

Comment: @User2020201 it looks good to me.